# Django - Cannot display a form field as a textarea

Tags: python, django

I am declaring a field as a textarea. It works on my local server but not on my remote server. I am using Django version 1.2.3 on my local server and 1.2.5 on my remote server. Here is the code I am using to display a field as a textarea:

```
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Then, I display the form using:

```
{{ form.message }}
```

On my remote server, it continues to display as an input and not as a textarea. I triple checked to make sure the files were in sync. I used vim and ensured that the files matched each other. Is this because the newer version has a different way of turning inputs into textareas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart the Python interpreter on the remote host. If you're using mod_wsgi, this would mean `touch` the `.wsgi` file.

Comment: How would I restart the Python interpreter? What is the goal of editing the file?

Comment: It's a feature of mod_wsgi that makes it easy to restart the process.